# User Profiles cannot add connection

Tags: user-profile-service

I've added User Profiles, seems to be partly  operational as I can see a number of Profiles, but not all. I dont know how this happened as I havent added a connection. When i click 'Configure Synchronization Connections ' there is nothing listed so I go to click 'Create new connection', then a dialog opens stating
 'Cannot navigate to the requested page while User Profile Syncronizarion is running. Please wait ...'

I've resarted iis, but problem persists. 
I'm running winserver2008r2, SharePoint SP1 (14.0.4763.1000). I checked 'FIMSynchronizationService' and 'Forefront Identity Manager Service' in services and the Log On As, was set to local, I changed to Farm Account. Upon starting this service, errors as 'file mising'.

On the application page both the User Service Application and Proxy are started annd have been since install. However attempting to 'add connection' still get message:

'Cannot navigate to the requested page while User Profile Syncronizarion is running. Please wait ...'

What would be next step ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've re-installed user profiles and it appears to have worked.

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer if it solved your problem. It may help future users. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow given below steps to solve the issue.

1. Login to Central Administrations.
2. Click Application Management link.
3. In Service Applications click Manage services on server link.
4. Start User Profile Synchronization Service. If its already start, stop it and start again.